# Trouble with GetElementByID Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried just about every possible combination of code, except obviously the correct one. All I'm trying to do is get the element by id in javascript/JQuery and display it in an alert. After reading some similar posts I've put the script after the body, I've put the code inside of document.ready, window.onload, and still nothing. Ultimately I have a button and a .button css class with a grey background image and .button:hover with a white background image. I would like to remove the .button class and replace it with a .buttonSelected class which has a dark grey background. TIA

```
    <div id="PlanningNav">
        <a href="~/Planning/Planning.cshtml">
            <div id="AboutMe" class="Button">
                <img src="~/Resources/Images/icoAbout_Me.jpg" height="20" width="@Button_Width" /> 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   About Me
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var button = document.GetElementById('AboutMe');
    alert(button);
};
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var button;
       if (page.indexOf('About') > -1) { 
           button = document.GetElementById('AboutMe');
           alert(button.id); 
           // $('#AboutMe').removeClass('.Button');
           //$('#AboutMe').addClass('.ButtonSelected');
           // alert(button.innerHTML);
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: its getElementById()

Comment: There is no `GetElementById` but `getE....` You should open console and see the errors. this is how it should be done. Also don't mix Js with jQuery especially where jQuery is good at.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be something technical that I just didn't see. I did have my error console open and in visual studio 2015, but no errors were listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so instead of

```
document.GetElementById('AboutMe');
```

You need to use

```
document.getElementById('AboutMe');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is `Case Sensitive`, hence you need to make sure the casing.

your `GetElementById` would not work and as @dotnetom said, you need to change it to `getElementById`